# SwiftUI Image from Data

Tags: swift, swiftui

I am making a multi-platform SwiftUI app that loads the song artwork from an .mp3 file

```
let playerItem = AVPlayerItem(url: fileURL)
let metadataList = playerItem.asset.metadata
for item in metadataList {
    guard let key = item.commonKey, let value = item.value else {
        continue
    }

    switch key {
    case .commonKeyArtwork where value is Data :
        let songArtwork = UIImage(data: value as! Data)!
    default:
        continue                    
    }
}
```

I can also get data by using

```
let interpretedMP3 = AVAsset(url: fileURL)
```

and the metadata from that.

This all works fine for ios using `UIImage(data: value as! Data)!` but macos doesn't support uiimage so how am I supposed to make an image from this data?

Comment: you may find it useful to look at this "post" on cross platform image: https://www.alfianlosari.com/posts/building-cross-platform-swiftui-ios-macos-app/  It deals with ios and macos images.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

It is possible to make some platform-depedent image builder, like

```
func createImage(_ value: Data) -> Image {
#if canImport(UIKit)
    let songArtwork: UIImage = UIImage(data: value) ?? UIImage()
    return Image(uiImage: songArtwork)
#elseif canImport(AppKit)
    let songArtwork: NSImage = NSImage(data: value) ?? NSImage()
    return Image(nsImage: songArtwork)
#else
    return Image(systemImage: "some_default")
#endif
}
```

*Note: actually it can be also used `#if os(iOS)` etc, but Apple does not recommend to check OS directly until it is really needed explicit platform knowledge, but instead check API like above.

Comment: This is a fix, but not ideal since unfortunately there is an issue on image scaling if you convert from UIImage to Image. Apple need to fix this.

Answer (score -2):

It depends on what you want... But the best way I think is to use the same way implemented before:

```swift
extension Image {
    
    init?(data: Data) {
        guard let image = UIImage(data: data) else { return nil }
        self = .init(uiImage: image)
    }
    
}
```

Comment: There is no UIImage for macOS/AppKit.

Comment: What is the problem with using the same code with NSImage?

Comment: That is not what your posted code does and if this is what you mean with your answer it’s not very clear (hence my comment) and maybe you should improve it?